# How to undestand "to find himself alone"?

Tags: translation

I don't undestand how to translate this sentence:  "He went out into the street to find himself alone". He wanted to be alone? Or he went out and then there was nobody on the street?

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding the sentence as you quote it says indeed: "He went out, and there he saw (and got aware of) that there is nobody else." The situation includes a certain element of surprise.

However, you cannot say with total certainty what the author wanted to tell unless you have the broader context, i.e. more details on the situation described.